# PageLines theme: how to change the background color of the main content vs. entire page?

Tags: css, theme-options, design

I use PageLines free version, with WordPress 3.3.1, for this website: http://new.teleosis.org/?page_id=76

**I want the background color of the whole page to be light green, and the background color of my content area to be white**.

- I configure the **Page Background Color** in the PageLines settings, which affects the whole page. Whereas **Body Background Color** affects what they call the "Page content areas" like the footer.
- But I don't find the setting to change the background of a page body, is it even available in PageLines?

I hope I don't have to go into the CSS files for such a simple thing, but if I do, I appreciate any suggestions regarding which CSS file to modify and which properties to change/add. Thank you!

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This appears to be a **CSS/HTML** question, *not* a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, this is a very very VERY bloated theme.  Seriously, there's no reason a page that simple should take over 4 seconds to fully load.
In addition to the "way too many nested DIV's" issue, areas above and below the header menu span the entire page, so you can't actually change just that section of the header to white background.

From the looks of things, this theme creates its CSS dynamically on page load, so chances are it's going to be a hassle to fix.  I would really recommend you find a different theme that's easier to CSS edit, because any time you want to change something that's not in the "Theme Options" you're going to run into issues.

I know this isn't the answer you were hoping for, but you've kinda backed yourself into a corner with your theme choice.

Comment: Gosh. Thanks. Any suggestion for a simple theme?

Comment: http://fthemes.com/demo/YardZine/ - this might be along the lines of what you're looking for.  That's the demo page, you can download it here - http://wordpress3themes.com/yardzine-free-wordpress-theme/ - and they have quite a few others as well.  http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/zeecorporate - this is a nice one from WP.org, and they've got plenty of good free themes as well.  There's bound to be one that will at least work as a good starting point.  There's always stackoverflow for any CSS related questions while you're working on it as well.

Comment: These are helpful, thanks. I have found Shell Lite that I like, I think I'll settle for this one. http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/shell-lite

Answer (score 0):

The easy CSS fix is this:

```
#pagelines_content{background:#0000ff;}
```

You can plug this into the custom code in your WP Dashboard at PageLines > Settings > Custom Code > CSS Rules.

This is NOT their recommended way, but a very straightforward way to do it.