# WordPress with PageLines theme: how to change the background color of a page?

Tags: css, design, themes, configuration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PageLines theme: how to change the background color of the main content vs. entire page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44110/pagelines-theme-how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-main-content-vs-enti)

I use PageLines free version, with WordPress 3.3.1, for this website: http://new.teleosis.org/?page_id=76

I want the background color of the whole page to be light green, and the background color of my content area to be white (typical design). It seems like a super simple thing to do - or so I expected.

- I configure the overall background color in the PageLines settings as such: [screenshot](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/0mwJLIiUq5r9xWpD3q4W9ee3KXVMyPLPNLC65rDGCwM?feat=directlink)
- But I don't find the setting to change the page-content background color, is it even available in PageLines?

I hope I don't have to go into the CSS files for such a simple thing, but if I do, I appreciate any suggestions to do that too.

Comment: Yes, you will need to go into the CSS - this question should be on StackOverflow or Stack for Wordpress. Is it the blue footer you want to change or something else?

Comment: I didn't see there was a Wordpress site. You're right, I'll go there, thanks. What I want to change is the color of the main content, see here http://ow.ly/9oAfa

Answer (score 0):

On line 367 of `style.css` you need to change

```
.mcolumn-pad {
   padding-top: 2em;
}
```

to

```
.mcolumn-pad {
   padding-top: 2em;
   background: #FFF;
}
```